# download 32bit version of ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I have been trying to download Ubuntu 14.04 32bit version and I can not figure it out I've tried using the torrent. but it does not download the entire os.
could someone explain how to get this version I am kind of new to Ubuntu.
I'm trying to download the desktop version and would prefer to download it with the iso images. From this link

http://mirror.pnl.gov/releases/trusty/

Comment: You didn't specified which Ubuntu version... Server or Desktop? ISO Images or Torrent? Please, edit your question.

Comment: Here you go: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/

Comment: im confused on downloading those files

Answer (score 2):

To download Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit Desktop Version : [Click here](http://mirror.pnl.gov/releases/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-i386.iso)  ( from  http://mirror.pnl.gov/releases/trusty/)

To download Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit Desktop Version using **torrent :** [Click here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-i386.iso.torrent?_ga=1.206914134.474422496.1464252455) (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)